# SQL IF type logic help requested

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL problem that I have been stuck on for days.  So this is the context.  I work for a company where employees have timesheets.  Each timesheet has an ID but it is not unique because it is possible for an employee to have 2 timesheets for the same ID.  The difference is that normally when you submit the sheet your status is ‘Posted’.  But, sometimes people screw up their entries and it has to get re-submitted with changes.  Therefore, the status ‘Adjusted’.

The logic I need is the following

-Where timesheet ID’s only have one value (count=1) always use ‘Posted’ status. If there is only one value but it is not ‘Posted’ return an error string saying ‘Error’.

-where timesheet IDs have more than one value **and BOTH ‘Posted’ and ‘Adjusted’ show up as status** always default to ‘Adjusted’.  BOTH posted and adjusted must be present in this.

I have tried case and subquery but no luck.  I also have a column ‘timesheet post date’ and logic is earliest date is always posted and later date is ‘adjusted’, but in some cases the posting dates are identical.

so as you can see, I need to look at the duplicate count in one column, and then choose the value if that count is >1 from another column.

```
    SELECT t1.[Resource NUID]
      ,t1.[Timesheet ID]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Start Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet End Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Posted Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Status]
      ,t1.[RunSourceID]
      ,t1.[SpanStartDate]
      ,t1.[SpanEndDate]


    FROM [TIME_DW].[dbo].[Timecard_Timesheets]  as t1, [TIME_DW].[dbo].       [Timecard_Timesheets] as t2


   where t1.[Timesheet ID]=t2.[Timesheet ID]
   and t1.[Resource NUID]='e066308' and t1.[Timesheet Status]<>'Open' and t1.[Timesheet Status]<>'Submitted' 
 group by
 t1.[Resource NUID]
      ,t1.[Timesheet ID]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Start Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet End Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Posted Date]
      ,t1.[Timesheet Status]
      ,t1.[RunSourceID]
      ,t1.[SpanStartDate]
      ,t1.[SpanEndDate]
  order by t1.[Timesheet Start Date] asc
```

this is an example of an actual record that has two statuses

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting logic like this:

```
select timesheet_id,
       (case when count(*) = 1 and min(status) = 'Posted' then min(status)
             when count(*) = 1 then 'Error'
             when min(status) = 'Adjusted' and max(status) = 'Posted' then 'Adjusted'
             else NULL  -- this case is not covered in the description
        end) as new_status
from [TIME_DW].[dbo].[Timecard_Timesheets]
group by timesheet_id;
```

I don't understand what all the other columns are going in the code in the question.

Comment: this works for me partially.  what ideally I'd like to do is where a record has both status of 'posted' and 'adjusted', is simply hide or omit the 'posted'.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

First we count rows by TimeSheet `Id` (`CN`) and we assign a `row_number` (`RN`) ordered by "Adjusted" records first, then everything else (you might want to add an adjustment date as a 2nd order by to get the most recent one first).

Then we add an error status if the first and only row is not a `Status` of "Posted".

Finally we select out only the rows `WHERE RN=1`

```
DECLARE @TimeSheet TABLE (Id INT, Status VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO @TimeSheet (Id,Status)
VALUES
    (1,'Posted'),
    (2,'Posted'),
    (2,'Adjusted'),
    (3,'Adjusted')

;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS CN,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status='Adjusted' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RN,
           *
    FROM @TimeSheet
), Y AS
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN CN=1 AND RN=1 AND Status<>'Posted' THEN 'Error'
                    ELSE '' 
               END AS Error,
               *
        FROM X
    )

SELECT *
FROM Y
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: hi.  thanks for replying.  I think I get the logic but how do I now get the records back with this logic.  sorry, I'm limited in my sql ability and I know that's a basic question but I basically want to take your logic and hide if from the returned results

Comment: Delete the DECLARE/INSERT/VALUES parts at the top as that is just a test table I created for demonstration.  Then replace `FROM @TimeSheet` with your actual table name, `FROM [TIME_DW].[dbo].[Timecard_Timesheets]`.  If you want to omit the "error" records too, you can add `AND Error=''` to the very end after `WHERE RN=1`

Answer (score 0):

from your code, I think you were trying to do this :

```
SELECT 
    ts.[Resource NUID]
,   ts.[Timesheet ID]
,   ts.[Timesheet Start Date]
,   ts.[Timesheet End Date]
,   ts.[Timesheet Posted Date]
,   ts.[Timesheet Status]
,   ts.[RunSourceID]
,   ts.[SpanStartDate]
,   ts.[SpanEndDate]
FROM 
    [TIME_DW].[dbo].[Timecard_Timesheets] as ts
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN TimeSheetCount > 1 AND [Timesheet Status] <> 'Posted' THEN 'Adjusted'
            WHEN TimeSheetCount = 1 AND [Timesheet Status] <> 'Posted' THEN 'Error'
            ELSE 'Posted'
        END  NewStatus
    FROM (
    SELECT *
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.[Timesheet ID]) TimeSheetCount
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.[Timesheet Start Date]) RN 
    FROM 
        [TIME_DW].[dbo].[Timecard_Timesheets] as t1
    ) D     
) t2 ON ts.[Timesheet ID] = t2.[Timesheet ID]
WHERE 
    ts.[Resource NUID]  =    'e066308' 
AND ts.[Timesheet Status] <> 'Open' 
AND ts.[Timesheet Status] <> 'Submitted'
```

Comment: Hi...first off thanks for your help, greatly appreciated and this is getting me really really close.  However, As I use my test case of timesheet start date 4-1-2018 it appears the results are a) duplicating and b) not fully getting the results I need.

Comment: in other words, for that date, I should only have the 'adjusted' record come up because it takes precedence over the record that has the same ID but status 'Posted'

Comment: @evan could provide a sample that I can test, and provide also the expected results from the same sample? (not a picture). Try to cover all cases that you need in that sample,  it would be helpful for both sides.